# I am getting PII on a Query string in Google Analytics - how can I find out the source of it?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, query-string, pii

I am getting personally identifiable information on pages which contain a query string of;

www.examplesite.com/session?authenticity_token=EXAMPLE@EXAMPLEEMAIL.com

Does anyone know what an authenticity token is and when they are commonly used?

Answer (score 0):

An authenticity token is a reference to a session key, from above it seems that the email address is expected to  be the unique reference key for the session.